# Access Real Time on Computer

Tags: python, real-time, clock, low-level

currently I am attempting to access the OS clock using python.

Is there a sort of way I can access the clock value at this exact time and get a string that returns back lets say 12:00:00am PST or just the time? The timezone is a plus :)

I have currently done this `time.clock()` but nothing is giving me values back :/

Comment: `import datetime` ...
`print(datetime.datetime.now())`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import time

print time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p %Z')
```

For me, prints 12:21:51 PM EDT

Edit: Just want to clarify the place holders.

%I = Hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number [01,12].
%M = Minute as a decimal number [00,59].
%S = Second as a decimal number [00,61].
%p = Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM.
%Z = Time zone name (no characters if no time zone exists).

Answer (score 1):

time.ctime() will do the job. time.time() will give you the time in seconds, just brows through the module [time](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)